# Is URxvt's slow rendering because of the limited RAM'?

Tags: xorg

My [URxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) renders text very slowly, about 5 lines per second, and doesn't render fully when resized. Is this normal for `Xorg` and `URxvt`? Is this caused by the limited RAM on the RPi or by my configuration? Even `Xterm` is faster than `URxvt`, editing text with `vi` is such a pain.

My `~/.Xdefaults`

```
URxvt*transparent: true
URxvt*fading: 10

URxvt*scrollBar: false
URxvt*scrollBar_right: false

URxvt*foreground: #0000FF
URxvt*background: #000000
```

Is there any way to improve rendering speed?

Comment: Tried increasing the available RAM?

Comment: @Jivings I bumped it up to 192 MB and added a 1 GB swap on an external HDD. No visible effect whatsoever.

Comment: How about getting rid of the transparency? That usually takes quite a bit of effort on behalf of the WM.

Comment: @Jivings Slight improvement but lags so much when compiling.

Comment: What WM are you using? Are there any other settings that you could get rid of? Have you tried any other terminals with similar capabilities as rxvt? For example; terminator.

Comment: @Jivings I am using `awesome` wm. Other terminals are slower than urxvt except for rxvt of course.

Comment: @Jivings switching to `zsh` yields many performance improvements. Could bash be the cause?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why

Comment: Perhaps one writes output by character rather than by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with Awesome WM. It is written mostly in Lua, which runs on the Lua Virtual Machine. Since there is an abstraction away from the hardware, performance must take a slight hit (*citation needed*).

Even if you are using a distribution that supports Hard Float calculations, the Lua VM doesn't. So this will not improve performance as much as with other Window Managers.

As I've said, you can attempt to improve what you can in Awesome by disabling any extra features such as transparency and by increasing the available RAM to the GPU (forget about swap), but perhaps you might want to look at other WMs. I use [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/), which is simple like Awesome and is also tiling, so you might get on well with that. It runs on Haskell I believe, and performance for me has been great.

#### Sources:

- [LuaJIT comparisons](http://luajit.org/performance_arm.html)
- [Lua Raspberry Pi mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-03/msg00149.html)

Comment: I've been coding Haskell(hence my name) for a year now .Still Haskell scares me with `side effects` and `monads` .Especially `monads`, how hard is it to configure `Xmonad`?

Comment: @Haskeller: Easy enough for me to do it, with absolutely zero Haskell experience.

Comment: Wheres the package?Do I need ghc to compile XMonad?

Comment: @Haskeller: What is your distro?

Comment: I am using Arch Linux Arm.

Comment: I either installed it using pacman or yaourt in Arch.

Comment: Unable to compile https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=12483 .So many decencies out of date. Is this the package?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4482/discussion-between-haskeller-and-jivings)

Comment: Sorry, poke me tomorrow and I'll try and take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Anything running in Xorg is very slow right now due to the lack of 2D acceleration. Any redraws/re-sizes/etc tend to cause very high CPU usage, slowing everything else down to a crawl.

Turning off transparency will help fair a bit as it will reduce the CPU load that comes from performing the alpha blending.

Answer (score 1):

It's the font rendering.

For fast urxvt on pi3, I compiled the 9.22 source, configured with `--enable-256-color --disable-xft --disable-transparency`.

in `src/features.h` I removed an ifdef and a space to get
`#define LINUX_YIELD_HACK 0`

Nice and zippy now.